# To compute the factor group $\mathbb{Z}_4/\mathbb{Z}_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

how to compute the factor group $\mathbb{Z}_4/\mathbb{Z}_2$?

I made this example on my mind, so I don't know if it even makes sense.

To be more precise, I want to find all cosets that are elements of this factor group. I know it is of order 2 by Theorem of Lagrange, and that it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2$. But when I try to calculate the cosets, I get {0,1}, {1,2}, {3,0}.

Comment: In this instance it's easy: it has order $|\mathbb{Z}_4|/|\mathbb{Z}_2|$, so it has order $2$, and there's only one group of order equal to any given prime, so it has to be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2$. Can you be any more specific about what you want to know?

Comment: How do you make $\mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z$ a subgroup of $\mathbf Z/4\mathbf Z$?

Comment: Bernard, I take every element of $Z/2Z={2Z,2Z+1}$ and make the cosets $\{a+b: b \in Z/2Z\}$. But, I don't know if I can do it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the group $\Bbb Z/(4) = \lbrace 0, 1, 2, 3\rbrace$ and the subgroup $H = \lbrace 0, 2\rbrace$. Since $\Bbb Z/(4)$ is Abelian, $H$ is obviously normal. You have the cosets $0 + H, 1 + H, 2 + H$ and $3 + H$. Since $0, 2 \in H$, you have $0 + H = 2 + H = H$. The other cosets are $1 + H$ and $3 + H$ and these are equal. Hence,

$$(\Bbb Z/(4))/H = \lbrace H, 1 + H\rbrace.$$

Now $H + (1 + H) = 1 + H$ and $(1 + H) + (1 + H) = 2 + H = H$, so you have a group isomorphic to $\Bbb Z/(2)$ (under the isomorphism $1 \mapsto 1 +H)$.

Comment: But in this case H is $\mathbb{Z}_2$, so it is the subgroup {0,1}. It isn't? And when you make 1+H you get {1,2}, then 2+H={3,0} ...

Comment: @EuclidesStolf Do the elements $\lbrace 0, 1\rbrace$ form a group under addition modulo $4$?

Comment: Ah... no.... it does not. Yes, you are right. Now I see.

Comment: So doesn't make sense write $\mathbb{Z}_4/\mathbb{Z}_2$? Because $\mathbb{Z}_2$ isn't a subgroup of  $\mathbb{Z}_4$ ?

Comment: @EuclidesStolf Well, the subgroup $\lbrace 0, 2\rbrace$ of $\Bbb Z/(4)$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z/(2)$, because (among other things), it is itself a group of order $2$ and the only groups of order $2$ are $\Bbb Z/(2)$.

Comment: Ahh... now I see... Thank you @ÍgjøgnumMeg.

Answer (score 1):

We know that up to isomorphism, it has to be $\mathbb Z_2$, since the index must be $4/2=2$ and there is only one group of that order.

On the other hand, there is only one subgroup $\mathbb Z_2 \hookrightarrow \mathbb Z_4$, where $\mathbb Z_2=\{0,2\}$, so you can directly compute $\mathbb Z_4/\mathbb Z_2$.